# Measures for the Eccentricity of General Strictly Convex Smooth Closed Manifolds of Genus 0

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

> **Question:**
>   Are there any measures for how much the shape of a strictly convex smooth closed manifold of genus 0 deviates from that of a hyper-sphere of equal dimension?

In euclidean 2-space and in the special case when the manifolds are ellipses, such a measure is defined via the eccentricity.
An idea for generalizing eccentricity could be to use the quotient of the area bound by a curves' evolute over the area bound by the curve itself; that could also work for higher dimensions if the focal surface's topology isn't "too strange".